# How do I use Markdown in editMessageMedia (Telegram BOT API)?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, telegraf

Telegram has a method for changing the image, it accepts InputMedia:

```
{
    type: "photo",
    media: IMAGE, 
    caption: TEXT, 
    parse_mode: "Markdown", 
}
```

So, formatting doesn't work, even though I specified parse_mode.

My code

```
ctx.editMessageMedia({
    type: "photo",
    media: IMAGE,
    caption: TEXT,
    parse_mode: "Markdown",
}, message_id)
```

Comment: What programming language and library are you using? Have you tried surrounding `parse_mode: "Markdown"` with additional curly braces?

Comment: Node JS, Telegraf. No, how do I do this?

Comment: Added my answer - don't see anything particularly wrong with your code. Maybe it has something to do with how you're calling the `reply` / `send` function?

Answer (score 0):

This seems correct to me. Since you're using Telegraf, given the context you can also do `ctx.replyWithPhoto(...)` or `bot.telegram.sendPhoto(...)`.

Given the following example:

```js
bot.command('photo', ctx => {
    ctx.replyWithPhoto(
        {
            source: fs.createReadStream('img.jpg')
        },
        {
            caption: 'Some *really* _nice_ __images__',
            parse_mode: 'MarkdownV2'
        }
    ).catch(err => console.log(err))
})
```

... when I say `/photo`, it produces the following result:

[image: telegram result]

Comment: this works with replyWithPhoto
but it doesn't work with editMessageMedia
https://pastebin.com/b0yGhEka

Comment: If it's only the caption you want to edit, can you work with the following?

`bot.telegram.editMessageCaption(chat_id, message_id, null, '*new* caption', { parse_mode: 'MarkdownV2' })`